# How to remove all versions of node, including the one installed with brew?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, homebrew

On MacOS I've got a bit of a mess with node, so I'm trying to uninstall all versions of node. Here's what I tried:

```
$ node --version
-bash: /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node: No such file or directory
$
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/node
-rwxrwxr-x  1 hielke  admin  30994272 Oct  3 18:55 /usr/local/bin/node
$ /usr/local/bin/node --version
v6.11.4
```

As you can see, `node --version` refers to an uninstalled version 8.x of node. When I do `which node` however, it refers to `/usr/local/bin/node`, which is a binary of node version 6.x.

And from here I'm left with the following questions:

1. Why on earth does `node --version` refer to something different than `which node`?
2. And can I simply remove the `/usr/local/bin/node` binary?
3. And how can I remove the link to `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node`?

And most importantly: how can I clean up this mess so that I can install node completely fresh?

Answer (score 3):

1. `node --version` is referring to something different because your `path` is pointing there. use `echo $PATH` to print the path. Edit your path from your `bash_profile`. use `vim ~/.bash_profile` to edit your bash profile.
2. yes, you can just delete `/usr/local/bin/node`
3. Edit your `bash_profile` to change the path to your node

> Install the latest version of `node` you want and just edit
>   `bash_profile` to point the path to where the new binaries are.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I did that and it works, but now `npm` is still broken. `npm init` gives me `Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'`. I tried installing that module using `sudo npm install -g process-nextick-args`, but that simply gives me the same error. `which npm` gives me `/usr/local/bin/npm`, which is a symlink to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` instead of one installed with brew. In the folder `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/` there's only a `node` binary though. Any idea where I can find the correct `npm` installed with the node version 8 as installed by brew?

Comment: @kramer65 run `whereis node` and `whereis npm` to check all locations where does binaries exists, then follow my answer below and add them to your env PATH

Comment: can you try `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: nvm is a great option for installing node.

Answer (score 0):

in bash whenever you execute an expression or a statement in the shell, it first of all check if there is an `alias` to the executed command, if there is no alias it checks the environmental `${PATH}` variable. In your env path the previous location of node takes precedence in the env path variable, do this for a fix

```
 $ export PATH="/usr/local/bin/node:${PATH}"
```

if you want this to apply always edit your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file depending on your platform, the location and name might vary

on the current terminal you have to source your rc file

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile 
or
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

if you want to remove that previous location, you have to check if the node binary still exists at that location, if it does still exists, use the `rm` command to remove it